# Streaming remote files using Darwin Streaming Server over RTSP

Tags: video-streaming, darwin, rtsp

I have setup Darwin streaming server and I am able to successfully stream locally stored (hinted) video files over RTSP.I would like to know if it is possible to stream files stored on a remote web server?

The requirement is similar to what [media cache](http://www.wowza.com/addons/mediacache) solves for Wowza media server.